# 'i' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arraylist, data-structures, stack

So here is my coding declaration for Stacks named **s** and array list **word[]**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class STACK{ private: 
int top;
char word [5];

public:
    void createStack();
    void push(char newItem);
    void pop();
    char getStackTop();
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
};

int main ()
{
STACK s;
char word [5] = {'l', 'a',' b', 'e', 'l'};
s.createStack();
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
```

Here it meantion [Error] 'i' was not declared in this scope at the for loop

```
  s.push(word[i]);



  int n = 0;
  while (!s.isEmpty()){
  if (s.getStackTop() !=word[n]) break;
  s.pop();
  n++;
 }

 if (n<4) 
 cout << "not a a mystery " << endl;
 else
 cout << "a mystery " << endl;
}
```

Could anyone tell me what i'm missing?
**Edit: Already tried declaring but still no use? Should i declare it in class or in main?**

Comment: for (**size_t i=0**; i<5...

Comment: As the error says you haven’t *declared* the variable anywhere, you’re just trying to use it. Declare it somewhere first.

Answer (score 3):

Its just because of a few syntax errors.
You did not declare the variable i inside the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Here is the fixed version:

https://pastebin.com/i5eABPkD

Comment: Usually in the C++ tag, we don't answer on typographical/basic mistakes, we just comment.